# what are the consequences of a UDP 'error'?

Tags: udp, client-server

I have a server and client setup to use UDP communication. For now, I have the client sending a `0` to the server, and the server responds with a `1`.

I've read about how UDP does not guarantee the message reaches the server, and does not guarantee that it is correct without errors. Does this mean, in this case, that the server may sometimes think it has received a `1` instead of a `0`. Could this ever happen? (it hasn't happened to me in my tests so far) and are errors and dropped packets going to be more common on say, a mobile 3g connection?

I'm also wondering about something else I read. If I only send one packet, that multiple duplicate packets could be received by the server. Is this the case?

I realize I could use TCP, which will be safer. However, I am trying to create a very low latency program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that the server will receive a 1 instead of a 0, that would require a lot of stuff to go wrong.

UDP's "unreliability" just means, if the destination doesn't get it, nobody will care or try again - it's just gone. The sender side isn't checking, and the receiver side never knew about what it missed out on.